Best way to build `testTag` string throughout Compose heirarchy
I have a Jetpack Compose project that I want to add testTag modifiers to.
Ideally what I'd like to be able to do is build my tag as I proceed further down into my views
aka
Home
Home-Account
Home-Account-Password
Home-Settings
Home-Settings-Brightness
etc...
Does anyone have any suggestions? It doesn't look like there's any way to access the current testTag for a modifier, so I can't easily append them.

From your example tags Home-Account-Password it sounds like screens backstack. In that case if you are using compose navigation just listen to backstack and edit it to desired format
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, _, _ ->
    val routes = controller
        .currentBackStack.value
        .map { it.destination.route }
        .joinToString("-")

    Log.d("BackStackLog", "Screens backstack: $routes")
}

